# Unable to consume messages with Camel 3.3 and Google Pubsub

Tags: apache-camel, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a small groovy script with Apache camel that is attempting to pull messages from Google Pubsub. This works well on Camel 2.25.1, but camel 3.3.0 does not. Here is the script. I also looked at the [Camel 2.x to 3.0 migration guide](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html), but I am unable to find anything relevant to this issue, but perhaps I am mistaken and I would need some help.

My groovy version is 3.0.4 and I am using JDK 11.0.6

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='org.apache.camel', module='camel-core', version='3.3.0'),
    @Grab(group='org.apache.camel', module='camel-google-pubsub', version='3.3.0'),
    @Grab(group='org.slf4j', module='slf4j-api', version='1.7.30'),
    @Grab(group='ch.qos.logback', module='logback-classic', version='1.2.3'),
])

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder

main()

def main() {
    println "downloaded camel dependencies"
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext()

    context.addRoutes(new ReadFromQueueWithPubsub())
    context.start()
    addShutdownHook { context.stop() }
    synchronized(this){ this.wait() }
}


class ReadFromQueueWithPubsub extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    void configure() {
        from("google-pubsub://my_gcp_project:transaction-test-subscriber")
        .to("log:input?showAll=true")

    }
}
```

Here is the snippet of logs in debug mode. I can't see anything that's relevant here, but I may be mistaken.

```
2020-05-28 07:14:51 INFO  [o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext          ] - Apache Camel 3.3.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
2020-05-28 07:14:51 DEBUG [o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext          ] - Using ClassResolver=org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultClassResolver@25478603, PackageScanClassResolver=org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver@3c7dbf1f, ApplicationContextClassLoader=null, RouteController=org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultRouteController@2efbe938
2020-05-28 07:14:51 INFO  [o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext          ] - StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
2020-05-28 07:14:51 DEBUG [o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext          ] - Using HeadersMapFactory: org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultHeadersMapFactory@12459991
2020-05-28 07:14:51 DEBUG [o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext          ] - Using ReactiveExecutor: org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor@43114981
2020-05-28 07:14:51 DEBUG [o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext          ] - Warming up route id: route1 having autoStartup=true
2020-05-28 07:14:51 DEBUG [o.a.c.s.DefaultProducer                 ] - Starting producer: Producer[log://input?showAll=true]
2020-05-28 07:14:52 DEBUG [o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext          ] - Route: route1 >>> Route[google-pubsub://my_gcp_project:transaction-test-subscriber -> null]
2020-05-28 07:14:52 DEBUG [o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext          ] - Starting consumer (order: 1000) on route: route1
2020-05-28 07:14:52 DEBUG [o.a.c.s.DefaultConsumer                 ] - Init consumer: Consumer[google-pubsub://my_gcp_project:transaction-test-subscriber]
2020-05-28 07:14:52 DEBUG [o.a.c.s.DefaultConsumer                 ] - Starting consumer: Consumer[google-pubsub://my_gcp_project:transaction-test-subscriber]
2020-05-28 07:14:52 INFO  [o.a.c.c.g.p.GooglePubsubConsumer        ] - Starting Google PubSub consumer for my_gcp_project/transaction-test-subscriber
2020-05-28 07:14:52 DEBUG [o.a.c.i.e.BaseExecutorServiceManager    ] - Created new ThreadPool for source: google-pubsub://my_gcp_project:transaction-test-subscriber with name: GooglePubsubConsumer[transaction-test-subscriber]. -> org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.RejectableThreadPoolExecutor@7d726fa1[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0][GooglePubsubConsumer[transaction-test-subscriber]]
2020-05-28 07:14:52 INFO  [o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext          ] - Route: route1 started and consuming from: google-pubsub://my_gcp_project:transaction-test-subscriber
2020-05-28 07:14:52 INFO  [o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext          ] - Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started
2020-05-28 07:14:52 INFO  [o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext          ] - Apache Camel 3.3.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.078 seconds
2020-05-28 07:14:52 DEBUG [o.a.c.c.g.p.GooglePubsubConsumer        ] - Subscribing to projects/my_gcp_project/subscriptions/transaction-test-subscriber
```

Comment: Update: I was able to get this working on Camel 3.1.0, but 3.2 and 3.3 are broken.

Answer (score 1):

Closing this out: It looks like there's a bug open in JIRA for this [CAMEL-15064](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-15064) that affects versions >= 3.2